# In App Inventor Make TCP IP Client

Tags: android, port, tcpclient, beagleboneblack, app-inventor

Hi Guy's I'm new to programming Android device's I do have python, java, C#, C, C++, PHP, Bash and Visual Basic Experience but I'm new to this block programming, and I haven't done much work with forms. I'm trying to get make an application that posts data to an external IP. I have successsfully wrote a server and a windows based client, clicking buttons in my windows client posts data to the ip 192.168.1.9 port 9999. This is just in the testing phase to remote control a bunch of beaglebone gpio's. So far I've had great success with the windows side. In app inventor for android, However, I've created a series of buttons and tabs, different buttons post text or post and poll for response. The problem I have is that I can directly attach the web connector to 192.168.1.9 but when I add in the port 9999 it tells me the address is incorrect. The method I'm using is

```
when Screen1.initialize
do set Web1.Url to "http://192.168.1.9:9999"

when Button1.Click
do call Web1.PostText
             text > 0
```

Again, if I type in just the IP of the beaglebone I see its ethernet port go crazy when I click button1. It does nothing when I add in the port. Of course my server is running on 9999 since port 80 is reserved for the internet. Any suggestions?

Comment: probably this is not possible, see [issue 385](https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=385)

Comment: I'm a bit sad now, looks like I'm going to have to learn how to program forms in c#, Thanks Taifun

Comment: probably this [App Inventor Classic example](http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/TinywebIP) can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you a two-step solution.

**Step 1:**

Problem>>Develop an android app which is capable to communicate via TCP-IP.

Solution>> I hope you are familiar with MIT-APP Inventor-2. Import an extension called  **ClientSocket extension V0.4.3** available [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mitappinventortest/app-inventor-extensions/OCzEZC4FpEU) to app. Thanks to the developer of the extension.

**Step 2:**

Problem>>A server responding client request.

Solution>> I have written a Python code.

```
import socket               # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 9000                 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
print (host)
s.listen(5)
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   data=(str(c.recv(1024)))
   print data
   conn.commit()
   c.close()  
   cur.close()
```

Hope this will help.